# Swift code works in playground but not in command line tool

Tags: swift, swift-playground, command-line-tool

I'm very new to swift and I'm trying to write a simple regex app that takes user input of a file path and applies several regex replacements to the text file.

```
import Foundation

let shotFilePath = readLine()
// Use contentsOfFile overload.
// ... Specify utf8 encoding.
// ... Ignore errors.
let babySteps = try NSString(contentsOfFile: shotFilePath!,
    encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

let firetruck = #"Ay Ay Sir!"#
var firetruckYou = babySteps.replacingOccurrences(of: firetruck, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The problem is something with the last line of code. With a hardcoded string everything works however when I allow it to be entered by a user I get the following error:

- Missing argument for parameter 'range' in call

If I hardcode the babySteps string in a constant, no issue, but if I have it be imported from a file, things turn sour.

What is causing Swift to behave differently in the two instances? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the guy that originally posted this deleted his answer, but here was his very elegant solution:

```
let babySteps = try String(contentsOfFile: shotFilePath!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Thanks to Mojtaba who later pointed out the difference between String and NSString as well!

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the range to `NSString` method. For example:

```
let range = babySteps.range(of: String(babySteps))
```

---

#### Why?

Because you are using `NSString`. In Swift, we prefer to use `String` instead. They are different. Take a look at these two:

```
babyStepsString.replacingOccurrences(of: firetruck,
                                     with: "",
                                     options: .regularExpression,
                                     range: <#Range<String.Index>?#>)

babyStepsNSString.replacingOccurrences(of: firetruck,
                                       with: "",
                                       options: .regularExpression,
                                       range: <#NSRange#>)
```

As you can see, both methods are nearly identical but the `String` method takes an `optional` and you can pass `nil` or simply don't pass anything to it as it has a default `nil` value. **But** the `NSString` version **required** you to pass a range.

---

## Upgrade

You can implement an extension to make it more like the one you want:

```
extension NSString {
    open func replacingOccurrences(of target: String, with replacement: String, options: NSString.CompareOptions = []) -> String {
        replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: replacement, options: options, range: self.range(of: String(self)))
    }
}
```

Now your original code should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Now I guess I'll go and learn what ranges are. So if I'm understanding you correctly using String makes the range optional, because NSString cannot accept a nil value?